# C# how to set a combo box value based on saved property settings using string

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new on C# programming and wants to save the last selected item from a combo box using save property settings method.

I am able to save the last selected item using below code.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.model = modelBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

But cannot select it using below code (This is on initialize winform).

```
this.modelBox.SelectedText = Properties.Settings.Default.model;
```

Any suggestion would be ok, thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to set initial value to your combobox from Settings is it?

Comment: Yes, but i need to store the settings as a string not by index

Comment: what data you hold on the combo box? is it just list of texts you configured on the control or it is binding object?

Comment: its winforms so i guess hes not using bindings. maybe this works but i didnt test  `modelBox.SelectedItem = from item in modelBox.Items where item.Text == Properties.Settings.Default.model;` but as people saied before its better to store the selected index in your variable and restore the selected index by setting `SelectedIndex` to saied value

Comment: @Denis Schaf it is possible to do binding on winform. i use it all the time to fill comboboxes from table on data base and more.

Comment: while its possible its not very common. But yeah i agree with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the selected Index instead of the actual text:

```
//Save
Properties.Settings.Default.model = modelBox.SelectedIndex;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
//Restore
this.modelBox.SelectedIndex = Properties.Settings.Default.model;
```

The problem with your code is that `SelectedText` is not really ment to be used to set the Selected Item. Its more like a readonly property in your situation. While setting the Selected index actually changes the selection of the combobox

Comment: The `modelBox.SelectedItem = Properties.Settings.Default.model;` worked for me

Comment: ok glad that worked :)
keep in mind this only works as long as you store nothing but strings in your combobox. if the combobox contains other elements it mwill fail. But for now you problem seems solved :)